# Pulling/Outputting data from teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I'm using Teradata as a database and I'm trying to pull and output some data for it.

Here are the links to:
[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUBET.png)
[Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mPm.png)

I'm looking to figure out the queries for the following items.

1) What is the most common color and how many unique products have this color?

> SELECT TOP 1 COLOR
>
> FROM SKUINFO
>
> GROUP BY COLOR
>
> ORDER BY Count (*) desc;

this allowed me to get the color: Black.

But now I don't know how to get the number of products

2) What sku has the largest profit per unit and in which stores is this sku being sold?

Thank you!

Comment: I thought Teradata did most of the querying for you. Can't you ask it what you want or use the green-screen?

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. But what I'm looking for specifically is the code on how to pull these outputs.

Comment: For the 1st question. I got: 

SELECT TOP 1 COLOR
FROM SKUINFO

GROUP BY COLOR
ORDER BY Count (*) desc;

this allowed me to get the color: Black.

But now I don't know how to get the number of products

updated in my post!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `WHERE` clause subquery approach:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS ProductCount
FROM SKUINFO
WHERE Color IN
  (SELECT TOP 1 COLOR
   FROM SKUINFO
   GROUP BY COLOR
   ORDER BY Count (*) DESC);
```